# how on Word can you make a title with a drop-down list and with each option the text changes?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to put a drop-down list in MS Word document and when we click on each choice the text should  change, how to do it? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

### Simplest method is to save your headings and attached text as AutoText and use a Building Blocks Gallery Content Control

If you save your heading and related content as an AutoText entry with a particular category for your list, you can use a Building Blocks Gallery Content Control set for that gallery and category to list and insert your heading and related text.

If you want, you could save that Content Control, itself, as AutoText, a Quick Part, or another Building Block for easy insertion if you want to have headings and paragraphs.

You can save keyboard shortcuts in your template holding the Building Blocks to insert particular building blocks (such as the Building Blocks Gallery Content Control) in your document easily.

If in a Mac environment, Content Controls are not something that can be created through the user interface without programming unless using John Korchock's Add-In. However, AutoText is available as is the [AutoText List Field](https://support.microsoft.com/office/591cd0be-589b-4aae-9624-db427a19a1c8).

*In writing this, I am assuming that you are familiar with these Word features and had not thought to use them. Links are provided below to explore some of these, if you want more information on them, it should be the subject of a separate question.*

It would also be possible to have **macros** that react to the content of a drop down to insert text. In my opinion, that is considerably more complex and many environments do not permit the use of macros.

It is also possible to use legacy formfields and complex IF and cross-reference fields to produce this result. Again, in my opinion, the Building Blocks Gallery Content Control is the simplest method.

If in a Mac environment, Content Controls are not something that can be created through the user interface without programming unless using John Korchock's Add-In. However, AutoText is available as is the [AutoText List Field](https://support.microsoft.com/office/591cd0be-589b-4aae-9624-db427a19a1c8).

**References to spots in my webpage on Automated Boilerplate in Microsoft Word:**

- [AutoText and AutoComplete](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#AutoComplete)
- [Building Blocks Gallery Content Control](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#BBGalleryContentControl)

Microsoft Help Pages:

- [Create Reusable Text Snippets](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-reusable-text-snippets-0bc40cab-f49c-4e06-bcb2-cd43c1674d1b)
- [Quick Parts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/quick-parts-4ffef7c5-7596-4e95-9faf-41c771847a7b#bm1)
- [Easily Accessing Quick Parts Without Going to Insert > Quick Parts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/easily-access-quick-parts-without-going-to-insert/6a4d04f9-696a-4f2f-9e53-fbfbce86fb4f)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

1. Bookmark the dropdown list (e.g DD). Suppose the dropdown options are: A, B, and C
2. Insert this nested IF code where you want the text to appear:

{IF {DD} = "A" "TEXT FOR OPTION A" {IF {DD} = "B" "TEXT FOR OPTION B" {IF {DD} = "C" "TEXT FOR OPTION C"}}}

CAUTION: The field code will not update automatically, so select it each time and press the F9 key to update it.